# Line breaking in \newcommand

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I defined a new command for highlighting some text parts:

```
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\colorbox{black!5}{#1}}
```

Unfortunately, when the text becomes to long it overlaps my margins.
The keyword ignores the margin of the table, as well as the margin of the hole document.

```
\keyword{exp: c=wordExp \{ if(\$c.matches(``a string'')\{ 
\textbackslash\textbackslash do something \}) \}}
```

[image]

Can I tell my command to make a newline or force it to break after X centimeters?

Thx.

Comment: you could put the argument into a `parbox` or a `minipage`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @barbarabeeton's advice. I don't recommend the name `\keyword`, however, because it is defined elsewhere in some classes. So, the `newcommand` can look like this:

```
\newcommand{\KEY}[1]{\colorbox{black!5}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}
```

Observe this `-2\fboxsep`, which serves to align the `colorbox` with the text above and below. Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\KEY}[1]{\colorbox{black!5}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

\begin{tabular}{|p{.4\linewidth}|p{.5\linewidth}|}
\hline
Something here to fill half & 
Something here to fill half the line width
\KEY{exp: c=wordExp \{ if(\$c.matches(``a string'')\{ 
\textbackslash\textbackslash do something \}) \}}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]